# Login with a REST service (services module)

Tags: users, services, 8

I work with Drupal 7 (services 3.x) to implement a REST service. When I test a login request with this script:

```
$service_url = 'https://dev.mysite.org/api/blog/user/login.xml'; // .xml asks for xml data in response
$post_data = array(
  'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'admin',
    );
$post_data = http_build_query($post_data, '', '&'); // Format post data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded
// set up the request
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // have curl_exec return a string
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);             // do a POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); // POST this data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
// make the request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // output to command line
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print "RESPONSE:\n";
var_dump($response);
// parse the response
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$session_cookie = $xml->session_name .'='. $xml->sessid;
print "SESSION_COOKIE: $session_cookie";
file_put_contents('session_cookie.txt', $session_cookie);
```

I receive this error:

```
* upload completely sent off: 29 out of 29 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: Missing required argument name
< Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2014 02:39:45 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9
< Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Sun, 09 Feb 2014 02:39:45 +0000
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< ETag: "1391913585"
< Set-Cookie: DRUPAL_UID=-1; expires=Tue, 04-Mar-2014 06:13:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.dev.labdoo.org; secure
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host dev.mysite.org left intact
RESPONSE:
string(0) ""
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/myuser/Desktop/test.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 /home/myuser/Desktop/test.php(23): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')
#1 {main}
```

- My REST service configuration is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

- I followed this example to test the [service](https://drupal.org/node/910598).
- It is activated the session authentication in the Services module.
- It is activated application/x-www-form-urlencoded, json, xml....

**UPDATE**

It seems which the code has multiple mistakes....  I replaced my post_data variable for this:

```
$post_data = array(
  'name' => 'admin',
  'pass' => 'admin',
);
```

And now, I send the login request correctly ( I receive a 200 response),
but now, I try to parse the response message to get the cookie-session, I don't receive any response message. I am getting an error like this:

```
* upload completely sent off: 21 out of 21 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 21:35:36 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9
< Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 21:35:36 +0000
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< ETag: "1392240936"
< Set-Cookie: DRUPAL_UID=-1; expires=Sat, 08-Mar-2014 01:08:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.dev.mysite.org; secure
< Content-Length: 1316
< Content-Type: application/xml
< 
* Connection #0 to host dev.mysite.org left intact
RESPONSE:
string(1316) "
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/lbd/profiles/labdoo/modules/contrib/services/includes/services.runtime.inc on line 417

Call Stack:
    0.0000     334912   1. {main}() /var/www/lbd/index.php:0
    0.0347    4175712   2. menu_execute_active_handler() /var/www/lbd/index.php:21
    0.0348    4176376   3. call_user_func_array() /var/www/lbd/includes/menu.inc:517
    0.0348    4176756   4. services_endpoint_callback() /var/www/lbd/includes/menu.inc:517
    0.0366    4343036   5. call_user_func() /var/www/lbd/profiles/labdoo/modules/contrib/services/services.module:218
    0.0366    4343036   6. rest_server_server() /var/www/lbd/profiles/labdoo/modules/contrib/services/services.module:218
    0.0385    4449312   7. RESTServer->handle() /var/www/lbd/profiles/labdoo/modules/contrib/services/servers/rest_server/rest_server.module:39
    0.0432    4532668   8. services_controller_execute() /var/www/lbd/profiles/labdoo/modules/contrib/services/servers/rest_server/includes/RESTServer.inc:46
    0.0436    4534132   9. _services_controller_execute_internals() /var/www/lbd/profiles/labdoo/modules/contrib/services/includes/services.runtime.inc:106
    0.0436    4534176  10. _services_authenticate_user() /var/www/lbd/profiles/labdoo/modules/contrib/services/includes/services.runtime.inc:162
```

**UPDATE 2**

I am trying to create a new user to check if my error is related to working with an admin account. I tried (now with the script postman for Chrome) to create a new user via REST... It would be easy... but I wasn't ( I tested username,name,email,mail)...[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have fixed the problem. It was a bug in the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module. I updated from `7.x-3.5` to the `7.x-3.7` version, I followed the @sibiru tutorial and it started to work well.

Comment: Hi i am already using 7.x-3.15 but i am still getting this error

Answer (score 2):

This is the important bit:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: Missing required argument name

Just change your payload to

```
$post_data = array(
  'name' => 'admin',
  'password' => 'admin',
);
```

Comment: Sorry @Clive, Is no it correct yet? I added the payload  as you comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try watching this screencast, it helped me

- [Drupal 7 Tutorial - Web Services: Basics Part 1](http://www.wdtutorials.com/2013/04/11/drupal-7-tutorial-web-services-basics)

  and also take a look on X-CSRF-Token issue too
- [Drupal 7 Tutorial - Web Services: Basics Part 2](http://www.wdtutorials.com/2013/05/07/drupal-7-tutorial-web-services-basics-part-2)

Comment: Thanks @sibiru. For the first tutorial, I followed all these steps, It helped me to fix my bug.... and with  the second tutorial, I would not implement tokens in my service yet.... I would like implement a simple authenticated service, tokens could be too complicated.